# could not able to find database name and source data name in mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" 
               connectionString="Data source = YOUR DATA SOURCE NAME; 
               Initial Catalog=YOUR DATABASE NAME; 
               Integrated security=true;" 
               providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

i m facing an problem .this code asks me to replace database name in mvc4.

where can i find the YOUR DATA SOURCE NAME and  YOUR DATABASE NAME?

my database connection string name is:

```
Data Source (LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\hasibk\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\try7\try7\App_Data\Database1.mdf";Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework
```

database name is 
 `C:\USERS\HASIBK\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2012\PROJECTS\TRY7\TRY7\APP_DATA\DATABASE1.MDF`

Answer (score 0):

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ConnectionString" 
           connectionString="Data source = (LocalDB)\v11.0; 
           Initial Catalog=Database1; 
           Integrated security=true;" 
           providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```